# JavaFX - After changing Label Text, Animation resets

Tags: animation, javafx

I have a dynamically filled GridPane, where I'm animating the first row and column, so if there is a lot of information, the user doesn't get lost, because the row and column jumps to the selected area.

(Animating: I created two GridPanes, one for the first row and the second one for the first column, then I move the labels into the new GridPanes and finally starts the animation.)

It looks like this: 
[image]

The user can also select some cells and change the content (using KeyEvents).
But there is a problem, when I **change the text of a label**, the animated row and column **jumps back to their first position**, but I don't understand why. It happens only, when I change the text, the CSS style for example is not causing the issue.

Comment: Is hard to guess without any code, but have you tried storing the position of the state of the animation during the KeyEvent ? And starting from this position if such is set?

Comment: Thank you for your hint, I considered that, I'll try that, previously I was looking for an easier solution. My current workaround starts the animation directly after the text has changed (keyEvent), so it will bring that node back to the selected area, but it blinks a little bit, so it's not perfect.
Anyway, do you think that there could be an option, where the Animation won't stop, when there's a change on the node?

Comment: The animation will stop on the keyevent anyways, (unless you **create a task** for the animation) which is a even harder solution. But you can restart it from the desired position right in the event handler which would still be quite fast (maybe even continuous to the user).

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "restart"? Should I move my pane to the desired position or just manually start the old animation?
I'm starting the old Timeline again, which is not really the best solution, because it blinks.
Are you sure, that any animation will stop after keyevents have been activated? Because I think that it only stops, if someone changes the "basic layout".
Anyway, so now I'm trying to restart with `timeline.play()` but it blinks, I thought I could try to use `timeline.playFrom()` but it also didn't react. I don't understand the exact behaviour of it.